# Installation of Sails JS get stuck in Windows 10

Tags: sails.js

I recently installed Node.js ( v4.4.5 (includes npm 2.15.5)). My OS is Windows 10 Home edition.
I have been trying to install Sails but it gets stuck at

*└── grunt-contrib-less@1.1.0 (async@0.9.2, less@2.5.3).*

Please help me get rid of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without any error message it will be hard to help you

Comment: Thank you Martial. I am also really confused as there is no any error message. It just gets stuck.

Comment: Probably you have unmet dependecies. Remove node_modules folder, or checkout package.json you were editing inside